# Can't BundleInstall the vim-css-color plugin using Vundle

Tags: vim, installation, bundle

I added `Bundle 'ap/vim-css-color'` to my `.vimrc` under the `" original repos on github` section and ran `:BundleInstall` but I do not see it the list of newly installed bundles that shows up in the new buffer. In fact even if I comment out a `Bundle` line in my `.vimrc` and do `:BundleClean` the plugin remains in that list.

How can I get Vundle to work?

my `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible

filetype off  " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" Bundle 'tpope/vim-haml'
Bundle 'ap/vim-css-color'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Bundle 'vim-scraper/packages'
Bundle "pangloss/vim-javascript"
" vim-scripts repos
Bundle 'surround.vim'
Bundle 'delimitMate.vim'
Bundle 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
" Bundle 'skammer/vim-css-color'
" Bundle 'AutoComplPop'
" Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
Bundle 'snipMate'
Bundle 'tComment'
" Bundle 'mru.vim'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'matchit.zip'
Bundle 'Vimball'
Bundle 'ScrollColors'
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
```

Result after running `:BundleInstall`

```
" Installing bundles to /home/max/.vim/bundle
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-haml'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup'
Bundle 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Bundle 'surround.vim'
Bundle 'delimitMate.vim'
Bundle 'hail2u/vim-css3-syntax'
Bundle 'skammer/vim-css-color'
Bundle 'snipMate'
Bundle 'tComment'
Bundle 'mru.vim'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'matchit.zip'
Bundle 'Vimball'
Bundle 'ScrollColors'
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Helptags
```

Comment: You have two plugins with the same name: you should cleanup your config and make up your mind. Do you want `skammer/vim-css-color` or `ap/vim-css-color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by romainl, you have clashing names. Vundle doesn't really differentiate between Github usernames when saved, just the name of the repositories. In other words, it doesn't notice if you switch from `skammer/vim-css-color` to `ap/vim-css-color`. Take a look at how it stores the bundles:

```
$ ls -l .vim/bundle/
total 88K
[..]
drwxr-xr-x  5 tim tim 4.0K 12.04.13 00:31 vim-autoclose
drwxr-xr-x  4 tim tim 4.0K 11.05.13 03:27 vim-css-color
drwxr-xr-x  6 tim tim 4.0K 12.04.13 00:30 vim-easymotion
[..]
```

Therefore; clean up your mess:

1. Remove/comment out *both* `*/vim-css-color` entries
2. Restart Vim - let Vundle refresh the list of bundles
3. `:BundleClean` - notice how it'll ask if you want to remove `Bundle 'vim-css-color'`, and not specifying the Github username.
4. Re-add/uncomment `Bundle 'ap/vim-css-color'`
5. Restart Vim
6. `:BundleInstall` - now installs `Bundle 'ap/vim-css-color'`

Comment: Sounds about right but god how is this mess supposed to be better than the old school manual installation? Yak shaving FTW.

Comment: @romainl Aye, this is rather messy, and it seems that Vundle doesn't actually know what plugins is bundled or where they are from other than the `Bundle` list in a .vimrc. It seems to be that this could be solved by prepending the filename or something, but maybe there's a reason for it. Either way this is somewhat rare, but easy to fix once you understand why I still believe Vundle is the most efficient way of handling plugins.

Comment: Thank you timss. Worked as you said it would.