# Vim Color Scheme Plugin Not Working

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, color-scheme, vundle

I am trying to setup Vim with Vundle and I am right now trying to use the color scheme plugin for Vundle. However, whenever I try to source and save my ~/.vimrc file, it tells me that the color scheme that I am trying to use is not a valid color scheme. Note: when I source my ~/.vimrc file, the color scheme works but I get an error that:

```
Vundle error: Name collision for Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim.
Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim previously used the name "Vundle.vim".
Skipping Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim.
```

and an error that:

```
Error detected while processing function vundle#config#bundle..<SNR>8_check_bundle_name
```

My ~/.vimrc file:

```
  1 set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
  2 filetype off                  " required
  3
  4 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
  5 " set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
  6 " call vundle#begin()
  7 " " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
  8 " "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
  9 "
 10 " " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 11  Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
 12  Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
 13 "
 14 " " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 15 " call vundle#end()            " required
 16 " filetype plugin indent on    " required
 17 "
 18
 19 " Some settings to enable the theme:
 20  set number
 21  syntax enable
 22  set background=dark
 23  colorscheme molokai
```

Comment: Your most important vundle setup lines (and some others, such as `filetype plugin indent on`) are commented? When you copy-paste something, *check* the results!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't BundleInstall the vim-css-color plugin using Vundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486032/cant-bundleinstall-the-vim-css-color-plugin-using-vundle)